# Highcharts Speedometer with multiple dial in the gauge chart in Angular14

Tags: angular, highcharts, gauge

I want to implement a speedometer with an inner and outer(additional indicator in a triangle shape) dial using Highcharts gauge in Angular14. Is there any way, to show an additional indicator using the Highcharts gauge in Angular14?
My expectation is shown in the figure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShH5w.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need a custom plugin, which creates a triangle dial when `series.isTrianglePoint` is set to `true`. Plugin is inside a `customPlugin.ts` file and is imported inside app component. Then, you can use two series with two separate dials, one with `isTrianglePoint: true`.

---

**Live demo:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-jdhsit

**API Reference:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-wrapper
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.gauge.dial